# Shift boolean horizontally in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe of booleans, called `original`:

```
original = pd.DataFrame([
    [True, False, False, True, False],
    [False, True, False, False, False]
])

  0     1     2     3     4
0 True  False False True  False
1 False True  False False False
```

And I want to create the following boolean dataframe (all to the right of a True should now be True):

```
  0     1     2     3     4
0 False True  True  True  True
1 False False True  True  True
```

I've accomplished this as follows, but was wondering if anyone had a less cumbersome method:

```
original.shift(axis=1).fillna(False).astype(int) \
    .T.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill').T.astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `cummax`

```
original.cummax(1).shift(axis=1).fillna(False)

       0      1     2     3     4
0  False   True  True  True  True
1  False  False  True  True  True
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
original[original].shift(1,axis=1).ffill(1).fillna(0).astype(bool)
Out[77]: 
       0      1     2     3     4
0  False   True  True  True  True
1  False  False  True  True  True
```

Comment: Nice answer @wen